# Binomial GLM output - interpretation

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

I have some binomial mortality data that I'm working on in R.

The dataset looks like this:

[image: dataset raw data]

this is head() of the dataset, mortality = 1 and alive = 0, i have three different treatments in A and B that are the following:

[image: Treatments]

which gives me 9 possible combinations. When i want to analyse the data i fit it to a glm with binomial distribution:

```
mod<-glm(mortality~A*B,dat,family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

then run anova from car package

```
Anova(mod)
```

which gives me the following output:

```
> Anova(mod) # Analysis of variance glm
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: mortality
                LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
A                 6.5195  2   0.038398 * 
B                 1.8309  2   0.400337   
A : B            13.6219  4   0.008605 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

When i then run post-hoc test with package emmeans i get the following output:

```
> multcomp::cld(emmeans(mod, ~A|B),
+               Letters = letters, reversed = T) # Post-Hoc test glm
B = Metabolite:
 A           emmean     SE      df asymp.LCL  asymp.UCL .group
 Low         19.566   1963.405 Inf  -3828.637   3867.77  a    
 Normal      1.705    0.544    Inf   0.639      2.77     a    
 Metabolite  1.686    0.487    Inf   0.732      2.64     a    

B = Normal:
 A           emmean     SE  df asymp.LCL   asymp.UCL .group
 Metabolite  19.566 2346.718   Inf -4579.917   4619.05   a    
 Low         1.992     0.616   Inf     0.786      3.20   a    
 Normal      0.693     0.463   Inf    -0.214      1.60   a    

B = Low:
 A           emmean     SE    df   asymp.LCL  asymp.UCL .group
 Low         2.944    1.026   Inf     0.934      4.96    a    
 Normal      2.442    0.737   Inf     0.997      3.89    a    
 Metabolite  1.992    0.616   Inf     0.786      3.20    a    

Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
      then we cannot show them to be different.
      But we also did not show them to be the same.
```

What I'm confused about is the output from the last code (emmeans). I don't get how the estimated marginal mean can be 19 with SE around 2000 for A low B metabolite (see above) and same for A metabolite B normal.

Also, i do get significance in the ANOVA but not in the post-hoc test. I know these are two different type of tests and this is possible. However, I think something might be wrong from my side.

Could also be good to mention that mortality is numeric in my dataset.

Comment: Looks like complete separation, i.e you only have 1s in the two offending subgroups. Here's a good link about it: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logistic-regression-and-what-are-some-strategies-to-deal-with-the-issue/

Comment: Thats correct! I guess complete separation is the explanation then. One of the answers in the post was simply

"The easiest strategy is "Do nothing". This is because that the maximum likelihood for other predictor variables are still valid as we have seen from previous section. The drawback is that we don’t get any reasonable estimate for the variable that predicts the outcome variable so nicely."

So I'll guess that's what I'll do in this case.

Comment: In particular, I suspect that all of the individuals in the combinations with `emmean` values of 19.566 died, so providing those`emmean` estimates doesn't add much. In this particular case, it probably would make more sense to display mortality percentage estimates instead of log-odds estimates. If you had data on the time to death, then if I'm correct about all those individuals dying you could might get around the perfect separation by using a survival model.

Comment: I don't have data on the time to death unfortunately, I just have data on whether they died or not.